# Java: HDFS copy directory

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

Is there a simple way to copy a HDFS directory to another directory in Java?

For example, how would I move the contents of /user/abc/pudding to /user/def/pudding?

I'm looking for some HDFS equivalent to UNIX's cp command which I can do programmatically with Java.

**Note:** I'm aware of [FileSystem](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) but it only seems to allow me to copy from my local machine to HDFS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try one of the copy methods in [FileUtil](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.html). For example:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil;
```

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();  // if necessary
FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(conf);  // if necessary

FileUtil.copy(
    fileSystem, new Path("/path/to/src"),
    fileSystem, new Path("/path/to/dst"),
    false,  // move if true
    conf
);
```

Answer (score -1):

I remember FileSystem could copy directory from HDFS to local file system

Comment: I'm looking to copy from a HDFS directory to another HDFS directory.

Comment: distcp,a greate distribute copy program